# Arduino Pro Micro Analog Pinouts

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-leonardo, analogread, arduino-pro-micro

I have the Arduino Pro Micro and I would like to use all the **analog** pins that I can on it.

It currently looks like it has a total of **9 Analog pins** that can be used.
[image]

A0, A1, A2, A3, A6, A7, A8, A9 and A10.

However, I am unsure how to call these pins since all of those are also **digital pins**.

Would A0-A3 be defined as:

```
#define analog1 A0;
#define analog2 A1;
#define analog3 A2;
#define analog4 A3;
```

While the other pins would be this?:

```
#define analog5 4;
#define analog6 6;
#define analog7 8;
#define analog8 9;
#define analog9 10;
```

Then just call:

```
analogRead(analog1);
analogRead(analog2);
.....
analogRead(analog8);
analogRead(analog10);
```

Would that be the correct way of defining the 9 analog pins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the [Pro Micro core](https://github.com/sparkfun/SF32u4_boards), they are called A0, A1, A2, A3, A6, A7, A8, A9 and A10. There is no need to "special case" the others, since the pins are known as both.

Comment: So you're saying its **= A0, = A1, = A2, etc...** or are you saying its just **= 0, = 1, = 2, etc**?

Comment: Analog pins in the Arduino libraries are prefixed with "A".